# SQL Error when using inner join on visual studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, xampp

Im trying the inner join in visual studio then suddenly this error pops up:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9LlT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bumBO.png)

I'm using Visual Studio 19 and Xampp for connection (Im new to visual studio) I've seen a lot ways but nothing  happened. Can you guys share me some tips on how to solve this one.

I tried to enable remote connection on myphpadmin user accounts but still nothing happened..

Comment: Are u able to connect your sql server from management studio? also, you can try connection from Visual Studio > View > Server Explorer. If you are able to connect from VIsual Studio then take connection string from properties and use it.

Comment: Oh hi thanks for the reply.! is it necessary to use SSMS to do inner join? I watched a lot of videos and they are using SSMS, Is there no way can do it without using management studio(Beginner question mybad).
@Amit Verma